# norwegian/scandinavian letters in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

I want to be able to get hex from scandinavian letters, and be able to convert it back. is there any possibility for this. I thought maybe it has to be binary first, but I seem to not find this answer online.

For english this works:

```
from binascii import*

def From_String_to_hex(String):
    variable = bytes(String, encoding='ascii')
    return int(str(binascii.hexlify(variable), 'ascii'), 16)

def From_Hex_To_String(Hex_nuber):
    return str(binascii.unhexlify(hex(Hex_number)[2:]), 'ascii')
```

how to able to do the same with scandinavian letters (æøå)?

Comment: Could you change your code into a complete executable example and explain what result you expected and what result you're getting? Currently unclear what you want to accomplish. Also note that those Scandinavian letters are extended ascii of which there are many versions, so perhaps you should stick to unicode and not mention ascii at all?

Comment: If you're looking to *encrypt* your message, have a look at AES or PGP. If you're looking to *encode* (convert) it into ASCII, have a look at base64